# How to limit autocomplete results with devbridge jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the devbridge jquery autocomplete plugin
https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete
and I have gotten it to work. However, I found that when you start typing in the searchbox, it doesn't actually limit the result set (as it does on the demo http://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/). All it does is start highlighting some of the suggestions in blue, leaving all the other ones in place.

Here is my code:

```
var options = {
    serviceUrl: 'reps/names',
    minChars: 2
};
var autoComplete = $('#edit-field-rep-contact-name-value').autocomplete(options);
```

I see a bunch of settings on their API, but can't figure out which one would limit the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should limit results from the server side if using server side search. If using local lookup then specify value for lookupLimit:

```
var options = {
    minChars: 2,
    lookup: [], // Lookup data here
    lookupLimit: 10
};
```

See sample here: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete#usage

Comment: Thanks. I did actually fix this by limiting the search from the server side. However, I was able to do so still using my javascript code above, with the option serviceUrl

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$("#edit-field-rep-contact-name-value").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(mySource, request.term);

        response(results.slice(0, 10));
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see 'source' as valid option on the doc page. How do I use this? What is mySource? and request.term? I am using ajax, so not sure if that makes a difference.